# Math term for Associative arrays/Maps/Dictionaries

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What would be the equivalent math concept for associative arrays/maps/dictionaries?

EDIT: Disregard mutability. FYI,off topic, the reason why I ask this question, is that I want to calculate the distance(or similarity) between two maps given that I have a distance function for each entity(or key) in the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function ($A \to B$). If that doesn't work for you, try a set of pairs (subset of $A \times B$).

Note that something like mutable state is not common in maths, outside of computer science.